# Complete Scroll Scouting without joining the College of Winterhold

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I'm playing through Dawnguard and have got up to the 'Scroll Scouting' quest.

Is it possible to complete it without joining the College of Winterhold? The quest description says to ask in the College but the door is locked. My character is a Nord with no interest in Magic at all, so it doesn't make much sense to join the College.

Comment: You have to join, I'm not sure you have to cast magic. I think you're able to join via dragon shout alone.

Comment: That's a bit annoying.... theres no other way of getting into the College?

Comment: Nope. If you're on PC, you can try manually adjusting the quest forward via the console (to whatever happens after the college), but otherwise you'll have to join, even if you never touch the college again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually skip out the College by going straight to [Septimus Signus's outpost](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Septimus_Signus%27s_Outpost). All you get at the college is an objective to go to the outpost, so you're able to cut out the middle-man if necessary.

Comment: Urag was always a pain to talk to